# What is the difference among these sentences?

Tags: past-tense

What is the difference among these sentences:

Question:

> Why were you so tired yesterday?

Answer:

> 1. Because I jog all morning.
> 2. Because I was jogged all morning.
> 3. Because I had been jogging all morning.
> 4. Because I had been jogged all morning.

Comment: Would tell us about your thoughts. What do you think about those 4 answers? What is your paraphrase? Also, the title and examples are not completely matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following definitions:

> **Jog** *verb*
>   1 [no object] Run at a steady gentle pace, especially on a regular basis as a form of physical exercise
>   2 [with object] Nudge or knock slightly: *a hand jogged his elbow*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/jog)

Your #1 and #3 use definition 1. If you meant that you meant that you were tired due to all the exercise, then #3 works because the past perfect indicates a completed action - in this case, the action leading to your tiredness the day before. However, the present tense of #1 ("Because I jog all morning.") indicates a recurring activity - you habitually use your mornings for jogging. It doesn't directly answer why you were so tired on a specific day (*yesterday*).

Your #2 and #4 use definition 2.
If you meant that you were tired from being pushed around all morning (and presumably having to work to maintain your balance), then both #2 and #4 work (both indicate completed actions, in this case performed on you).